# Android: layout_below and layout_alignParentBottom

Tags: android, android-layout, vertical-alignment, bottom-up

So I have the following layout

```
ScrollView

RelativeLayout
    TextView1
    EditText1

    TextView2
    EditText2

    TextView3
    EditText3

    TextView4
    EditText4

    TextView5
    EditText5: 
         android:id="@+id/txtPassword"

    LinearLayout: 
         android:id="@+id/Linearlayout1"
         layout_alignParentBottom="true" 

         Button1
         Button2
```

Here's the problem
When I click the **txtPassword** EditText to enter some text **Button1&Button2** from the LinearLayout *overlaps* or becomes on top of **txtPassword**

Someone suggested that I use **android:layout_below="@id/txtPassword"** for the Linear Layout but that makes the **layout_alignParentBottom="true" useless** because it will put the LinearLayout right below txtPassword and not at the bottom.

EDIT: Here's the Full Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/signatureScroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/signatureLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/Meaning"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMeaning"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#505050"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMeaning"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Comments"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtSignatureComments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Comments"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/line2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/line2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtSignatureComments"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Duration2"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDuration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtDuration"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/line2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtHours"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgDuration"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Hours"
            android:inputType="number|textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#505050"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMinutes"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtHours"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Minutes"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|text|textMultiLine"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#505050"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtException"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtHours"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Exception"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgException"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtException"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/line2" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnrException"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgException"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtExceptionDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spnrException"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="14sp" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPerformance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtExceptionDesc"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@string/PerformanceBased"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPerformance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPerformance"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/line2" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnrPerformance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgPerformance"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spnrPerformance"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Username"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textAutoComplete"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="12sp" >

        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_detail_bg"
                android:text="@string/Sign"
                android:textColor="@drawable/button_detail_txt"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/button_detail_bg"
                android:text="@string/Cancel"
                android:textColor="@drawable/button_detail_txt"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Post your layout so we can reproduce the same behavior and fix it

Comment: Adding the layout_below wouldn't make the align parent bottom useless.  It would force the linear layout to follow BOTH rules-  it would align to the bottom and be directly below the password field, stretching to fit (or squeezing, depending on screen size).

Comment: @GabeSechan Hello Gabe, What do you suggest?

Comment: @AlexBcn Hello Alex, I have included the full layout in my post.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have included the full layout in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see if this can be fixed using different windowSoftInputMode settings. You could try to set
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" for this specific activity. It will than move up the UI if the keyboard is visible and focused on a edittext. 
adjustResize can have the effect that some views overlap when the keyboard is visible.

Comment: That didn't work either somehow layout_alignParentBottom="true"  is causing the linear layout to appear on top of txtPassword

Answer (score 0):

use android:layout_below="@id/txtPassword" for the LinearLayout will work and doesn't make alignparentbottom="true" useless.

try it

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_below="@id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
```

When you use a Relative Layout and the Keyboard will be opened you LinearLayout will be above the keyboard

I'll suggest another solution and I think it will work:

Use a LinearLayout as parent and the last LinearLayout height fill parent and set the gravity bottom try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/signatureScroller"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/signatureLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/Meaning"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMeaning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#505050"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/Comments"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSignatureComments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Comments"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="250"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/line2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/line2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDuration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/Duration2"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDuration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/line2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtHours"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Hours"
        android:inputType="number|textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#505050"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMinutes"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtHours"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Minutes"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|text|textMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#505050"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtException"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/Exception"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgException"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/line2" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnrException"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtExceptionDesc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLength="250"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPerformance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/PerformanceBased"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPerformance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Image"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/line2" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnrPerformance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Username"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textAutoComplete"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" >

    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_detail_bg"
            android:text="@string/Sign"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_detail_txt"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_detail_bg"
            android:text="@string/Cancel"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_detail_txt"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```